# 7-Zip Error: there is no such archive

Tags: 7zip

I was trying to use 7-Zip on the command line and kept hitting the following error:

```
PS> 7z.exe a -t7z \\Path-to-archive\my-archive.7z \\Path-to-files\*
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18


Error:
there is no such archive
```

Could not find anything wrong, and this command had always worked in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that 7z.exe does not like / allow hyphens in the name of the archive. I still have some on my path - that works fine. But changing my command to the following worked.

```
PS> 7z.exe a -t7z \\Path-to-archive\myArchive.7z \\Path-to-files\*
```